# Spring - What is right way to response file stream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller which returns file stream using ResponseEntity class. 
But I'm not sure if the resource is closed after finished the method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/VMS-49001/playlist/{listName:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> playlist(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @PathVariable String listName) throws IOException {

    String hlsPath = getHLSPath(request.getParameter("dt"), listName, OtuEnum.URLType.HLS);
    Path filePath = Paths.get(hlsPath);

    if (filePath.toFile().exists()) {
        Path fileNamePath = filePath.getFileName();
        String fileName = "";
        if (fileNamePath != null) {
            fileName = fileNamePath.toString();
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(filePath.toFile().length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")).headers(headers)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(Files.newInputStream(filePath)));
    } else {
        String errorMsg = "404 file not found";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/html"))
                .body(errorMsg);
    }
}
```

if you see below code fragment, Files.newInputStream(filePath) implements Closeable, so it should be closed after use but I can't find the code closing it. :

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .contentLength(filePath.toFile().length())
    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"))
    .headers(headers)
    .body(new InputStreamResource(Files.newInputStream(filePath)));
```

To response file stream, is it good to serve the file with this code? Or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring 4.1 your approach will work there is no issue in it.
Here below is another approach in case if you want to look :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/VMS-49001/playlist/{listName:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> testphoto() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/images/no_image.jpg");

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"));
headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```